# Как импортировать html файл в другой html файл c помощью JS/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как импортировать html файл в другой html файл c помощью JS/jQuery? Мне нужно избежать дублирования кода.

Comment: Что такое "jQwery"?

Comment: фреймворк......

Comment: А. jQuery, может?

Comment: Да, опечатка. Я не пойму, зачем задавать такой вопрос?

Comment: 1) вы хотите трафик сэкономить, или просто для порядка? 2) что в вставляемом хтмл (навигация, статья, калькулятор, ...)?

Comment: 1) для порядка и для уменьшения размера файл. Не хочу дублировать код. 2) несколько div

Comment: Чокнитесь со своими фреймворками скоро. Банальные задачи решить не можете без сторонних библиотек...

Comment: @Doofy, есть инструменты подходящие под задачу и не очень. Сторонние библиотеки, как и стандарты и браузеры делают просто люди.

Answer (score 3):

Существует огромное количество способов включить один HTML в другой.

Способы композиции можно разделить на основные типы по месту/времени отработки:

1. во время публикации (генератор статических сайтов, например Jekyll / GitHub Pages)
2. на сервере, при обработке запроса HTML (SSI `<!--#include...`, или любые языки и шаблонизаторы)
3. на клиенте (далее рассматривается она)

Если вам есть дело до SEO, то лучше проконсультироваться по поводу применимости композиции на клиенте.

Вариант с React-компонентом: если включается не документ с текстом, а интерактивный элемент (например калькулятор или корзинка), то его лучше не делать HTML-ем.

Вариант с jQuery с дополнительными запросом: `$("#content").load("menu.html")`

Вариант без библиотек с дополнительными запросом:

```
function include(selector,address){
    fetch(address).then(resp => resp.text())
        .then(data => { document.querySelector(selector).innerHTML = data } )
}
```

Вариант с js-bundler (например, в webpack loader): HTML при сборке (во время публикации) преобразуется в js-строку в составе бандла, который подгружается целиком.

Вариант с "Web Components": в этом случае включаемый HTML больше изолирован.

Существует также множество вариаций этих и других способов.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector(selector).appendChild(html);
$("#elem").append(html)
```