# include блоки в простом HTML не через iframe

Tags: html, css

вопрос, а есть ли возможность, в простом HTML сделать include блоков, но не через iframe? Вот пример у меня левое меню будет на всех страницах одинаковое, чтобы не вносить в каждую страницу по очереди изменение, можно ли код меню вынести в отдельный файл, а потом на страницах его просто подключать?

Может есть какой-то инструмент, который может упростить подобную задачу?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1173630/395779

Answer (score 0):

Для этого вам понадобится использовать серверный язык программирования (например, php) или javascript - получать html-код меню через ajax и вставлять его в нужный блок. Второй вариант менее предпочтителен (в общем случае).

Кроме того, вы можете компилировать HTML локально, используя какой-либо препроцессор.